# Golang: Passing a URL as a GET parameter

Tags: url, go, get, parameter-passing, url-parameters

I want to get an URL as a get aparameter

ex: example.com?domain=site.come?a=val&b=val

the problem when i use

```
query := r.URL.Query()
domain := query.Get("domain")
```

to get the domain name it give just **domain=site.come?a=val**

I think because when the r.URL.Query() meet **&** it consider it as a new parameter

does anyone know how can I solve this problem

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to URL-Encode your query string, [like this](http://play.golang.org/p/BqHo_cqUFk):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    query := make(url.Values)
    query.Add("domain", "example.com?foo=bar")

    fmt.Println(query.Encode())
}
```

Which outputs `domain=example.com%3Ffoo%3Dbar`.

You can set that string as a `RawQuery` of an [`url.URL`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) value and if you then access the query like you did, it will have the correct value.

If the URL is correctly encoded then you should be able to run the [following code](http://play.golang.org/p/9sKnBD-mej) with your URL value and get the correct result:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    query := make(url.Values)
    query.Add("domain", "example.com?foo=bar&abc=123&jkl=qwe")

    url := &url.URL{RawQuery: query.Encode(), Host: "domain.com", Scheme: "http"}
    fmt.Println(url.String())

    abc := url.Query().Get("domain")
    fmt.Println(abc)
}
```

This prints:

```
http://domain.com?domain=example.com%3Ffoo%3Dbar%26abc%3D123%26jkl%3Dqwe
```

(the complete URI with the encoded parameter called "domain")

```
example.com?foo=bar&abc=123&jkl=qwe
```

(the decoded value of said parameter)

Comment: I'm not the one who send the Url, I just get from another service

Comment: Then you'll have to work with what you have (cutting `domain=site.come?a=val`) or call the other guy and tell him to fix his code because his query string is invalid.

Comment: He did the change he encoded the url and still the same problem when I get the domain it gave me just **domain=site.come?a=val** without the **&b=val**

Comment: I have edited my answer. The other guy probably did the encoding by hand and forgot to encode `&` as well.

Comment: it's works but i used another he just put the domain between [ ] and it works perfectly